# JUnit method dependency

Tags: java, junit

I would like to ask a simple question about the best practice of testing methods. Lets say I have a class like this,

```
public static class MyClass {
    private int num;

    public MyClass(int num) {
        this.num = add(num);
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    private int add(int num) {
        return num + 1;
    }
}
```

Is it better to write a single test method like this

```
Assert.assertEquals(3, new MyClass(2).getNum());
```

or to stub the add method and write a test method for constructor to assert inner num value and getNum seperately? I know it is a simple class and no need for such complications for this one but I wanted to point out the issue with a simple example. It would be appreciated if you explain your answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say your test **fails**.

Will you be able to see right away *where your error is located*? **No**. You'd have to check both methods manually.

Let's say your test **succeeds**.

Can you be sure *both of your methods work correctly*? **No.** They both might do something not intended just returning the checked for value *by accident*

So my clear advice on this: **One test per method.**

Comment: But that also means to depend on reflection for stubbing private methods and parameters of the class.

Comment: You're UNIT testing - which means you test the **outside contract** of that class. If you have private methods that don't add to the fact that your public methods fail or succeed something is off.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should test both ways - by stubbing `private` methods and without stubbing `private` methods.

Isolation of unit test methods is important but execution of full logical path is equally important too so test both ways and name your test methods accordingly.